# rqt plugin not listed

Tags: plugin, ros-kinetic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I tried everything mentioned in other posts and I still can't see my own plugin in rqt. I did --force-discover, I deleted the config file but it won't show.

I am wondering if I am missing some PATH variables or if I need to compile it differently. My plugin works when I run "rosrun gcs_gui gcs_gui". "rqt -s gcs_gui" returns that no plugin with this name was found. Any ideas?

Update: I was obviously missing the plugin.xml. But there I don't know how I need to set it up. What is my class type? I programmed the plugin in C++ but is the base_class_type rqt_gui_py::Plugin anyway? Do I need to use a python file somewhere?

Vincenz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292303/rqt-plugin-not-listed/) by [Vinni](https://answers.ros.org/users/35442/vinni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Vinni,

it's rather difficult to help you without any further information.
I suggest you use this (great) repo [catkin_create_rqt](https://github.com/leggedrobotics/catkin_create_rqt) which creates a boilerplate for an RQT GUI with properly set CMakeLists.txt and plugin export file.
Then you can just copy and past your functions to the newly created boilerplate.

Regards,

Marco.

---

Originally posted by [Femer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26134/femer/) with karma: 253 on 2018-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vinni](https://answers.ros.org/users/35442/vinni/) on 2018-05-25**:
Hi Marco,
that is actually how I started off (well, with catkin_create_qt_pkg). I altered my code from there but it is not running. I will try setting it up as another package and see if I can get that to work. Main problem for me is setting up the plugin.xml correctly...

**Comment by [Vinni](https://answers.ros.org/users/35442/vinni/) on 2018-05-25**:
I get a strange error like this:
Failed to load nodelet [rqt_gcs/View_1] of type [rqt_gcs/View]: Could not find library corresponding to plugin rqt_gcs/View. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually...

**Comment by [Vinni](https://answers.ros.org/users/35442/vinni/) on 2018-05-25**:
Worked in the end. Great tool.

**Comment by [Femer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26134/femer/) on 2018-05-26**:
good to hear that it worked eventually! What was the issue?

**Comment by [Vinni](https://answers.ros.org/users/35442/vinni/) on 2018-05-29**:
I tried somehow merging it right away with my old files. That didn't work. Simply running the script and executing the files worked. Unfortunately my workflow is not done yet. I can't get it to work the way I'd like to... Any idea? See https://answers.ros.org/question/292328/gui-creation-through-rqt